# iOS - canOpenURL returns false for an installed app when app is locked in MDM Single app mode

Tags: ios, nsurl, kiosk-mode

The following API
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622952-canopenurl
returns false for an installed app when the device is locked in single app mode via MDM.
When the app is not locked in Single app mode it returns the right value(true if the app is installed, false otherwise)
Is that intended behavior?

Thanks,
Aviya.

Comment: Is it returning false for the app's own URL scheme or is it returning false for the URL scheme of some other installed app?

Comment: @Rudedog for the URL scheme of some other installed app.

Comment: It sounds correct to me, because the app cannot open that url. It is locked in single app mode. `canOpenUrl` means literally that. It doesn't mean "is this url scheme registered"

Comment: *When this method returns true, iOS guarantees subsequent calls to the open(_:options:completionHandler:) method with the same URL will successfully launch an app that can handle the URL*

Comment: @Paulw11 That's exactly what I thought. just wanted to know if other encountered this before and have solid confirmation.